# AWS S3 Static bucket SSL issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured a static website with the following URLs in the bucket. HTTP urls are working as expected.

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

I have created a free SSL certificate from the certificate manager and in this certificate, the following domains are mentioned

```
example.com
www.example.com
```

Certificate Validation status: Success for both.

I navigated to Cloudfront and created new distribution. From the dropdown, I selected the certificate that was created.
See the other following settings:

```
Log Prefix  -
Delivery Method Web
Cookie Logging  Off
Distribution Status Deployed

Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) 
example.com
SSL Certificate www.example.com

Custom SSL Client Support   Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI) - (Recommended)
Security Policy TLSv1.2_2019
Supported HTTP Versions HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0
IPv6    Enabled
Default Root Object -
Last Modified   2020-10-24 00:07 UTC+1
Log Bucket
                    
Default (*)
Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
```

**Issue:** When I try the following URLs, getting **This site can’t be reached [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) took too long to respond.** Can anyone advise on what could be the reason?

```
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

Comment: What is the origin policy? Maybe you have it Match Viewer, thus your origin requires ssl as well?

Comment: There is no origin policy. Do I need to create one? At the moment, its blank

Comment: Your `d2wamfisdpa588.cloudfront.net` points to something. Where does it point to? Does it require https?

Comment: I don't understand from where aws got this name. I don't see that values when i edit the settings page. I have a registered domain name and its not d2wam.

Comment: Try with `d2wamfisdpa588.cloudfront.net/index.html` This is your website probably from s3? CloudFront will use that by default, if you don't create your own domain.

Comment: Yes but S3 bucket has a domain name......you are right it works with index.HTML. I deleted the that name from question  as I am helping a client. What should I do to enable https for this URL?

Comment: What you described doing with `example.com` seems correct. Did you wait a bit before checking if it works? The DNS changes are not immediate. Also make sure to delete caches from browsers when you test, or use fresh one.

Comment: Yes. I waited for 30 min. I use incognito mode instead of deleting caches. Https://d2wamfis.....URL works fine with https but not with https://example.com. do you think I missed any steps?

Comment: I added Cname record. Do you think I need to add A record in the DNS setting and point the https://d2wamfis.....URL ?

Comment: Oh yes. You haven't done that? If you use route53, you can create Alias A record from your domain to the domain provided by cloud front.

Comment: I am using Namecheap. I don't understand why do I even need to do this step? Why can't I specify my actual domain name on cloud distribution instead of it taking d2wam...cloudfront.net

Comment: Is it mandatory to use route53? Can I do any setting changes in Namecheap?

Comment: Yes, you can use Namecheap. In that case you can use CNAME record.

Comment: Added a new cname record with host as www and value as the cloudfront domain: d2wam....cloudfront.net. Waited for 1 hour and still http is not redirecting to https.  Anything else I am missing?